# Remove focus rectangle from ListBox item

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, listbox

How do you remove the focus rectangle from a silverlight ListBox? I have this code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
               ...snipped...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

and when i  run it i get the exception

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Invalid attribute value FocusVisualStyle for property Property. [Line: 47 Position: 38]
```

what am i doing wrong? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight the `ListBoxItem` type doesn't have a `FocusVisualStyle` property hence the error.

In order to acheive your goal you need to supply a new template for the `ListBoxItem`.  Form the Silverlight documentation you'll find the default template in [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Copy the ListBoxItem template into a Static resource (the App.Xaml would be a good place)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ListBoxItemSansFocus">
 <!-- copy of the rest of the control template here -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now remove the `StoryBoard` from the "Focused" `VisualState` and remove the final rectangle that has the name "FocusVisualElement".

Now in make your `ContainerStyle` property look like:-

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSansFocus}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```